# Vue putting form elements inside component accessing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know if this make sense. I think I got component happy and wanted to know the benefit of doing it this way. I have 2 form elements input and send button and I have created components for both elements. I ran into an issue sharing input value data between sibling and thinking is it worth the extra code. Should I just add it to one form component make more sense.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TextArea></TextArea>
    <SendButton></SendButton>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What additional functionality do these add that regular input elements wouldn't? If it's not much then the overhead of managing them may not be worth it. Sibling data communication can happen through a observer/event style mixin as noted [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced)

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to let sibling component communicated with other. The solution should be each component exposes some interfaces to let component invoker to get the data from each component, then the invoker will do something based on its own logic.

Comment: No other special functionality. Just get input value and send data. Maybe global theme to change button color on the fly but that probably can be done without using separate components

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great approach for encapsulation, especially when these elements have fancier styling or interfaces than their basic HTML equivalents. But you'll need to modify your components to receive passed-down data and pass up any changes. I'd do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TextArea v-model="myText"></TextArea>
    <SendButton @click="handleButtonClick"></SendButton>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Currently I have this wrapped inside a footer component. Do I write my business logic for the handleButtonClick here or do I need to pass the input value to the SendButton to process the data?

Comment: I'd probably but the logic in this component, not in `SendButton`; instead, I'd change `SendButton` to be a more generic component (say `UIButton`. That way, you can reuse the component in other circumstances. But ultimately, where you put your business logic is a subjective call, and heavily depends on the application.

Comment: Can I pass the input value to v-model='myText' from inside the TextArea component and process the data inside the footer component when users click on Send Button component?